# TypeError: Cannot read property 'upvotes' of null - React

Tags: reactjs, rxjs

Hi guys I'm new to react and I was following one of the react tutorials of Shaun Wassel.

I'm having trouble with where did I miss.

I tried to google but the reason also I wanted to post here is trying to get the nearest example to my problem and get more ideas on your answer and maybe a deep understanding of the problem.

**Error**

```
31 | <div className="row my-5">
  32 |   <div className="col">
  33 |   <h1>{article.title}</h1>
> 34 |   <UpvotesSection articleName={name} upvotes={articleInfo.upvotes} setArticleInfo={setArticleInfo} />
     | ^  35 |   {article.content.map((paragraph, key) => (
  36 |     <p key={key}>{paragraph}</p>
  37 |   ))}
```

**AddCommentForm**

```
const AddCommentForm = ({articleName, setArticleInfo}) => {

  const [username, setUsername] = useState('');
  const [commentText, setCommentText] = useState('');
  
  const addComment = async () => {
    const result = await fetch(`/api/articles/${articleName}/add-comment`, {
      method: 'post',
      body: JSON.stringify({username, text: commentText }),
      header: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      }
    });
    const body = await result.json();
    setArticleInfo(body);
    setUsername('');
    setCommentText('');
  }

  return (
    <div className="row">
      <div className="col-12">
        <h5>Add Comment</h5>
  
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="name">Name: </label>
          <input className="form-control" id="name" type="text" value={username} onChange={(event) => setUsername(event.target.value)}></input>
        </div>
  
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="comment">Comment: </label>
          <textarea class="form-control" id="comment" rows="3" spellcheck="false" value={commentText} onChange={(event) => setCommentText(event.target.value)}></textarea>
        </div>

        <button type="submit" className="btn btn-primary rounded-pill" onClick={() => addComment()}>Add Comment</button>
  
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default AddCommentForm;
```

**UpvotesSection**

```
const UpvotesSection = ({ articleName, upvotes, setArticleInfo }) => {
  const upvoteArticle = async () => {
    const result = await fetch(`/api/articles/${articleName}/upvote`, {
        method: 'post',
    });
    const body = await result.json();
    setArticleInfo(body);
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => upvoteArticle()} className="btn btn-sm btn-primary rounded-pill mb-2">
        Add Upvote
      </button>
      <p>This post has been upvoted <span className="text-danger">{upvotes}</span> times.</p>
    </div>
  );
}

export default UpvotesSection;
```

**ArticlePage.js**

```
import React, {useState, useEffect} from 'react';
import ArticlesList from '../Components/ArticlesList';
import UpvotesSection from '../Components/UpvotesSection';
import CommentsList from '../Components/CommentsList';
import AddCommentForm from '../Components/AddCommentForm';
import NotFoundPage from './NotFoundPage';
import ArticleContent from './Article-Content';

const ArticlePage = ( {match}) => {
  const name = match.params.name;
  const article = ArticleContent.find(article => article.name === name);
      
  const [articleInfo, setArticleInfo] = useState({ upvotes: 0,  comments: [] });

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const result = await fetch(`/api/articles/${name}`);
      const body = await result.json();
      setArticleInfo(body);
    }
    fetchData();
  }, [name]);

  if (!article) return <NotFoundPage />  
    /** show similar blog  */
    const OtherArticles = ArticleContent.filter(article => article.name !== name );
    
    return (
    <>
      {/** article page */}  
      <div className="row my-5">
        <div className="col">
          <h1>{article.title}</h1>
          <UpvotesSection articleName={name} upvotes={articleInfo.upvotes} setArticleInfo={setArticleInfo} />
          {article.content.map((paragraph, key) => (
            <p key={key}>{paragraph}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      </div>

      {/** comments */}   
      <div className="row my-5">
        <div className="col">
          <CommentsList comments={articleInfo.comments}/>
        </div>
      </div>

      {/** add comment */}   
      <div className="row my-5">
        <div className="col">
          <AddCommentForm articleName={name} setArticleInfo={setArticleInfo} />
        </div>
      </div>
      
      {/** other articles */}  
      <div className="row my-5">
        <div className="col">
          <h4>Other Articles</h4>
          <ArticlesList articles={OtherArticles} />
        </div>
      </div>
      
    </>
  )
}

export default ArticlePage;
```

Comment: The error is occurring for the component where you try to render the `UpvoteSection` component, Please include the code for that component as well and make sure to verify that you are getting the correct results by logging the value of `articleInfo` to the console.

Comment: Hi @subashMahapatra sorry, I thought I added the ArticlePage file. I just edit and the files above.

Comment: Please check the response of  `/api/articles/${name}`. it looks like it sets `setArticleInfo(body);` where `body` is very likely `null`.

Comment: @BrianBanttigue The default state for `articleInfo` seems to be fine. So there could be only one thing, after making the API call `articleInfo` is being set to the value `null`. The reason could be the API call fails with an error. Try making the API call in the `fetchData` function inside a `try...catch` block and additionally you can also create a new boolean state variable to track if the API call fails or not. For example `const [hasError, setHasError] = useState(false)`, set the `hasError` value to `true` inside the catch block.

Comment: @BenjaminEckardt  yes the response is null.

Comment: @subashMahapatra so i change this line ```const result = await fetch(`/api/articles/${name}`);``` to ```const result = await fetch(`api/articles/${name}`);``` so it works on the front end but it has error ```Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)``` on the same line.

Comment: The default state for `articleInfo` is not null that's why it works but I have no idea why you would make that change. At what endpoint the API responds correctly with the data for the articles? Aren't you supposed to call `/api/articles/some-article` to get a response from your backend?

Comment: @subashMahapatra the pointer ```"proxy": "http://localhost:8000/",``` has already / at the end so I was thinking I doubled that cause error.

Comment: @BrianBanttigue did u find the solution for this problem. i m also stuck in same problem.